# Facebook marketing API: How to get the optimization event

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

Using the NodeJs (and also the REST API) Facebook marketing API I'm trying to know which Ad Sets are optimizing which event (e,g, `add_to_wishlist`)

To do that I'm fetching all ad sets:

```
import bizSdk = require('facebook-nodejs-business-sdk'); // v8.0.0

bizSdk.FacebookAdsApi.init('myaccesstoken')
const adAccount = new bizSdk.AdAccount('act_XXXXX');
const adSets= await adAccount.getAdSets([bizSdk.AdSet.Fields.optimization_sub_event,bizSdk.AdSet.Fields.optimization_goal]);
```

I always get `NONE` for the optimization_sub_event field and `VALUE` or `OFFSITE_CONVERSIONS` for optimization_goal

More over, I tried to fetch [ALL fields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign#fields) possible and look for my event names but without success.

Is there away to achieve that using the API?

Comment: I am getting error that access token has expired. Is there a way to get the refreshed access token programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the field `promoted_object`.
The value for a custom event will have this structure:

```
promoted_object: {
  "application_id": "994*******818",
  "custom_event_type": "OTHER",
  "object_store_url": "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.*****",
  "custom_event_str": "my_custom_event_name" // this is what you want
}
```